# Easiest way to get the image of a map from google with markings on it?

Tags: google-maps

I have a hundred of UK postcodes and need to see a map with markings at that places. How can I do it using google maps API or maybe even just by creating some URL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding

Demo: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geocoding-simple.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).